# SEDE should remember what site you actually ran a query on in history and allow re-running on that site

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-deferred, data-explorer

Used to be, SEDE would always only link to the query for the site you actually last ran it on in history. That was often useful, but there was also a fair use case for just running it on the currently selected site, since usually that's what you'd end up doing anyway.

Recently, SEDE seems to have switched over to favor only the latter case. I'd like to go back to the earlier behavior, or, if possible, add an additional link (parenthesized or otherwise deemphasized?) with the original site. That way the primary and secondary use cases (current and past, respectively) would both be well supported.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your report.

SEDE uses the open source [Data Explorer](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer) project. You can suggest features and report bugs on [gitHub](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/issues).

While we are the originators of the project, it is currently run with a *lot* of community support, so it needs to be discussed and fixed there first.

Comment: I thought Meta was the place for that, no? Especially considering Tim Stone looks at Meta regularly...

Comment: Hrm. There are 5 issues there, total. But there are 258 bug reports here and 226 FRs. Perhaps the volume of traffic needs to be adjusted in some way.

Comment: I checked the most recent PR's that were merged by Nick and couldn't find anything that jumped out as being the root cause for this. I hope it is not related to a configuration change in IIS on the server SEDE is hosted.